# Space of polynomials is isomorphic to a proper subspace of itself

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, polynomial-rings

The following question is from Linear Algebra, Kaye and Wilson:

For each integer $n \ge0$, define $g_n(x)=x^n$

$1)$ Define $B:=\{g_n:n\ge 0\}$ show that B is a basis for $\mathbb{F}[x]$.

$2)$ Define the map $\phi:\sum \lambda_i g_i \to \sum\lambda_i g_{i+1}$ is injective but not surjective.

$3)$ Deduce that $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is isomorphic to a proper subspace of itself.

**My struggle**

Personally I think $1)$ and $2)$ are rather easy to prove but how would they be helpful to prove $3)$?

Comment: In part 2, do you mean *surjective*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is injective but not surjective, $\phi\bigl(\mathbb F[x]\bigr)$ is a proper subsepace of $\mathbb F[x]$ which is isomorphic to it (and $\phi$ is an isomorphism between them).

Comment: I think I am getting myself confused here. Why can $\phi$ be an isomorphism when it is not bijective?

Comment: The map $\phi$ **is** a bijection from $\mathbb F[x]$ onto $\phi\bigl(\mathbb F[x]\bigr)$.

Comment: Ah so the whole purpose of proving $\phi$ is not surjective is so that $\mathbb{F}[x]$ and $\phi(\mathbb{F}[x])$ are not equal and so the image is the *proper* subspace, right?

Comment: That is the idea!

Answer (score 1):

The key fact is that the image of $\phi$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{F}[x]$. The map $\phi$ is surjective onto this subspace, and it is injective, hence it is an isomorphism.